# Context manager: passing `__exit__` to

Tags: python, with-statement

I am writing a class that is essentially a wrapper around a file object. I want the class to be a context manager. My exit method is defined thus:

```
def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
    return self.file.__exit__(exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb)
```

All I've done is delegate cleanup responsibility to the underlying file object. Is this considered acceptable practice?

Comment: What would you do instead? Rewrite the code? I think it's best to call the parent method like you're doing. It can help to ensure version compatibility.

Comment: FWIW, what you're doing does look perfectly reasonable to my eye.

Comment: Could you give the full code?

Comment: Can you show us the declaration of your class ?